# Why can't I use .includes on a string in v-if when using a computed property?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Issue**

I am trying to determine whether or not a string includes some substring in Vues v-if directive. When I do, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: $options.language.includes is not a function
```

I am using Vue, Vuex and Ionic.

Where language is a computed property:

```
    computed: {
        language() {
            return this.$store.getters.getLanguage;
        }
    }
```

And the v-if looks as such:

```
<ion-label v-if="language.includes('en')">Play as guest</ion-label>
```

Here is what the computed property looks like in the store:

```
    state: {
        language: String,
    }
```

Mutations:

```
    mutations: {
        setLanguage(state, payload) {
            state.language = payload;
        }
    }
```

Actions:

```
actions: {
        setLanguage(state, language) {
            state.commit('setLanguage', language);
        }
}
```

Getter:

```
    getters: {
        getLanguage: state => state.language,
    }
```

And the language is set in the Ionic hook ionViewWillEnter:

```
    async ionViewWillEnter() {
        const info = await Device.getLanguageCode();
        this.$store.dispatch('setLanguage', info.value);
    }
```

Which fires when the component routing to is about to animate into view

**Attempts at solution**

1. I have made sure the computed property is of type string using typeof

```
<ion-label v-if="typeof language === 'string'">Play as guest</ion-label>
```

Which displays the label meaning the computed property is a string

2. I have tried using indexOf

```
language.indexOf('en') > -1
```

But this results in:

```
TypeError: $options.language.indexOf is not a function
```

And now I'm not quite sure how to proceed. I need to be able to check whether or not the computed property string includes some substring in the v-if directive. How can I achieve this? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . It's unknown what the component and store getter look like. Anyway, it's a mistake to put this logic into a template. This is exactly what computeds are for

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you are trying to support multiple languages in your html templates then I suggest looking into https://kazupon.github.io/vue-i18n/

Comment: @EstusFlask I have added more information that hopefully clears it up.

Comment: @bassxzero I definitely would use Vue I18n if I was building something of bigger scale!

Comment: Please, provide the whole code (containing only relevant properties) and not truncated snippets. This is good if you know what the problem is and want to show relevant parts, but it's not if you don't know what you look for.

Comment: @EstusFlask is that not what I have done? I feel like I have added every relevant avenue.

Comment: Actions, getters, and state are separated. There's no single `var store = ...`. See what MCVE is about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation for the error is that `language` is defined (otherwise the error would be about missing `includes` property) but doesn't have `includes` method. This means that it's an object or a function.

That it `typeof language === 'string'` condition is true at some point means that a value changes from a non-string to a string.

The problem is:

```
    state: {
        language: String,
    }
```

Unless this code belongs to component props that use special logic to check prop types and accepts constructors for primitive types, this means that `state.language` is assigned with `String` constructor, i.e. a function.

It should be:

```
language: null,
```

or

```
language: '',
```

or

```
language: 'en',
```

Notice that uninitialized value may need a special treatment, `null` is preferable because it designates that a value is uninitialized and results  in clear unambiguous errors. In this case it would be:

> Cannot read property 'includes' of null

It's a bad practice to put logic into templates. This makes it harder to debug and handle values, also may cause performance issues for intensive calculations. This is the use case for computed properties:

```
computed: {
    language() {
        return this.$store.getters.getLanguage;
    },
    isDefaultLanguage() {
        return !this.language || this.language.includes('en');
    }
}
```